# Undefined model method in form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create relationships between models in which a user is able to attend or unattend a certain a event.

In my **Presence** model I have:

```
class Presence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :event, class_name: "Events"
  validates :member_id, presence: true
  validates :event_id, presence: true
end
```

My **User** model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
      has_many :presences, foreign_key: "member_id", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :event_presence, through: :presences, source: :event
  ...
end
```

And the **Events** model:

```
class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :presences, foreign_key: "event_id"
    has_many :reverse_presences, foreign_key: "event_id",
                                       class_name:  "Presence",
                                       dependent:   :destroy
    has_many :members, through: :reverse_presences, source: :member

  def event?(other_event)
    presences.find_by(event_id: other_events.id)
  end
end
```

When I try to use the `event?` method in my partial:

```
<div id="attend_form">
  <% if event?(@events) %>
    <%= render 'unattend' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'attend' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I get the error: `undefined method "event?"'`

When I move the method to my the controller's helper the error doesn't show however I get a undefined method `"presences"`. I'm new to rails, but I understand that in the second case the method is not recognized because there is no relationship between the models in the helper but I can't figure out why it doesn't work when the method is in the model.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

def event1
  @events = Events.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: is the partial rendered by the `index.html.erb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your model should be called `Event`. Models in Rails are always singular.

---

The `event?` method is defined in the model, and you're attempting to call it in the view. Models and views are not connected in that way.

What you probably want to do is to determine if the person is attending or not attending the event already. What I would do in this instance, is call a method such as `current_user.attending?(@event)`. That's really what you want to do: determine if the current user is attending the current event.

The method would be defined like this:

```
def attending?(event)
  presences.exists?(event_id: event.id)
end
```

Comment: After a while I kind of figured it out I should had named my model Event instead of Events but I thought I could figure something out. I guess I'll just create another model and change everything. I tried your solution but I got the error `undefined method "attending?"`, maybe it has something to do with the model name. Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1):

`event?(other_event)` is a model attribute. just like any of your other model attributes. 
you have to call object on it. Like this

`#index.html.erb`:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>  #this line should go inside the index view
  <% render partial %>
<% end %>
```

`#partial`

```
  <div id="attend_form">
   <% if event.event?(event) %>
     <%= render 'unattend' %>
   <% else %>
     <%= render 'attend' %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

you can't pass `@vents` as an argument to the method: `(event?(@events)` because `@events` is an array of objects. so you want a singular instance.

Also, I think you have a TYPO in your `def event?(other_event)` method. it should be `other_event.id` not `other_events.id`.

UPDATE:

`@events = Events.find(params[:id])` is not an array and therefore CANNOT call the `each` method on it. This is a singular event. to follow the convention and avoid confusions, rename `@events` to `@event`.

```
@event = Events.find(params[:id])
```

Then in the view, do this:

```
<div id="attend_form">
   <% if @event.event?(@event) %>
     <%= render 'unattend' %>
   <% else %>
     <%= render 'attend' %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your solution however I'm getting the error (`undefined method `each'`)

Comment: Where is `@events` coming from? in the controller? `show` or `index` action? post the definition of `@events`.

Comment: In the controller index.`@events = Events.all`

Comment: so the above code is from the `partial` and the partial is being rendered by the `index.html.erb`. right?

Comment: move things around as above. let me know if that works. `@vents` is an array and so it should work to call `each` method on it unless it is `nil` and you should get `undefined method each on nil:NilClass`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, just updated the question. The `event1` action is where `@events` comes from and the partial is being rendered by `event1.html.erb`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52800/discussion-between-leo-costa-and-wali-ali)